# Login credentials using another website's credentials, synchronized log in

Tags: php, database, sharepoint, authentication, web

I have a sharepoint website that needs some credentials to login, and I am also developing another website that requires login credentials. How do I synchronize their login by taking credentials of one of them and using it on the other?

Like, when I login to the sharepoint, I will be logged in to my other website too when I navigate there.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start off by noting that this is not a question for StackOverflow. Posts here should contain an issue, an attempt at solving it, and any errors or bugs with it that you simply cannot solve yourself. Keep that in mind for future reference.

One way of approaching what you want is to create an interface between the two websites. Have a separate account system that is included for both websites. Basically separate any account systems you currently have in place and set them externally instead - and then include that onto your target pages. That's how I'd approach it anywho.